# tox.ini environment variable substitution issue

Tags: python, shell, tox

I'm working to use a directory environment variable inside of tox to pass an arg into a shell script that waits for database migrations to be completed before testing begins. When this runs though the argument is lost when echoing `$1` in the `.sh` script.

```sh
[tox]
envlist = py27
skipsdist=True

[testenv]
passenv = *
deps = -r {env:APP_ROOT}/requirements.txt
commands_pre = {env:APP_ROOT}/scripts/wait-for-db.sh {env:DBSENTINEL}/.db-migrations-ready
usedevelop = true
commands = py.test
commands_post = /bin/rm {env:DBSENTINEL}/.db-migrations-ready
```

I end up with

```sh
Darwin run-test-pre: commands[0] | /Users/alexander/projects/python-services/scripts/wait-for-db.sh /Users/alexander/projects/python-services/.db-migrations-ready
.db-migrations-ready
```

What I would except to echo out of my shell script is the full path seen in `run-test-pre` output `/Users/alexander/projects/python-services/.db-migrations-ready`. Instead only `.db-migrations-ready` is passing through.

If I change `pre_commands` to

```sh
commands_pre = {env:APP_ROOT}/scripts/wait-for-db.sh {env:DBSENTINEL}//.db-migrations-ready
```

Then I see the full substitution echo

```sh
Darwin run-test-pre: commands[0] | /Users/alexander/projects/python-services/scripts/wait-for-db.sh /Users/alexander/projects/python-services//.db-migrations-ready
/Users/alexander/projects/python-services//.db-migrations-ready
```

I'm guessing that this is related to an escape, formatting or argparse issue but not sure. What I need is to have {env:DBSENTINEL} unpack the directory path that is set and pass in to the shell script as `$arg1`.

Answer (score 0):

Single quotes appear to be the fix, and I believe this is related to [this](https://github.com/tox-dev/tox/issues/924) Github issue.

```py
commands_pre = {env:APP_ROOT}/scripts/wait-for-db.sh '{env:DBSENTINEL}/.db-migrations-ready'
```

```sh
Darwin run-test-pre: commands[1] | /Users/alexander/projects/python-services/scripts/wait-for-db.sh /Users/alexander/projects/python-services/.db-migrations-ready
/Users/alexander/projects/cloud/python-services/.db-migrations-ready
```